# TCP Server on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm Looking to set up a TCP Server on a Raspberry Pi to send strings from my PC to the RPi. The code I'm using returns a failure saying the Host and Port will not bind. I have my code below:

```
import socket

def handle_add(Data):
    name, rfid = Data.split(',')
    print(f'Added {name} to the database')

def handle_delete(Data):
    print("Deleted " + Data + " From the Database")

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 2555
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
try:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
except Exception:
    print("Error binding port")
server_socket.listen()

# Start Listening for incoming connections

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connected by", addr)
    
    # receive data from the client
    Data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    
    if ',' in Data:
        handle_add(Data)
    else:
        handle_delete(Data)
        
        
    # Send a response back to the client
    client_socket,sendall(b'Received')
    client_socket.close()
```

Comment: Post the full error traceback.

Comment: If you bind to localhost, you can only connect clients from the local system.

Comment: @KlausD. Traceback (most recent call last): server_socket.bind(HOST, PORT) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied

Comment: @MarkTolonen Such as devices on the same network? If so, Thats what I'm looking to do.

Comment: No on the same computer as the server. Bind to `'0.0.0.0'` or just `''` to listen on all network interfaces.

Comment: @MarkTolonen After attempting this, I still get an error if I use any port below 1200. Side note: Once this issue is fixed, When I connect to the raspberry pi from my PC, will I be using the IPV4 address to connect to the TCP Server?

Comment: Lower ports are reserved for admin processes.  Yes, the *client* uses the server IP address to know where to connect to.  The server itself could have multiple network interfaces (and IP addresses) which is why 0.0.0.0 is used to listen on all of them.  You could use one of the local IP addresses on the server to listen on only that network, but then the client would have to be connected to that network and use that server IP to access it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen When I Run the client code on my PC, The raspberry pi doesn't Acknowledge that connection has been established.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I got it to connect but the data is being received as "{Data}"

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the `f` for the format string, e.g. `f"{Data}"`, but without a [mcve] hard to say.